# how to kick start page loading bar initial request hitting server itself before rendeing view node.js and express.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

`enter code here`Im using nodejs and express js to serve my index page.before my index page render i want to show some loading bar in page.I place that loading bar in index page only.but I m getting delay before coming delay.how to avoid that delay? I m using angularjs and express js with ejs.can anyone help?

```
<div id="cmp-page-loading"
         style="background-color:#ffffff; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 111111; margin-top:0px;top: 0px">

        <div id="cmp-page-loading-center" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: relative;">

            <div id="cmp-page-loading-center-absolute"
                 style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 35%;height: auto;margin-top:-100px;margin-left: -50px !important;">
                <div class="cmp-page-loader">
                    <div class="LoadBorder" id="LoadBorder_one"></div>
                    <div class="LoadBorder" id="LoadBorder_two"></div>
                    <div class="LoadBorder" id="LoadBorder_three"></div>
                    <div class="LoadBorder" id="LoadBorder_four"></div>
                    <p style="font-size: 32px;text-align: center;line-height: 104px;width: 104px;">u</p>
                </div>
                <p class="page-loader-text" style="text-align: center;font-size: 28px;font-weight: 100;
                color: #000;position: absolute;width: 100%;padding-top: 50px;">Loading...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: res.render("index.ejs")

Comment: before this im calling some middlewares and finally rendering this

Comment: Please add the appropriate code in your question.

Comment: can i render loading bar before index renders

Comment: app.get('*', tokenUtility.initializeRequest, tokenUtility.getToken, tokenUtility.setTokenHeaderInCookie,
    tokenUtility.getBagInfo, handleRequest, handleError);

Comment: my request calling through this middlewares...in handleRequest im rendering the index.ejs

Comment: index index.ejs i kept that loading bar

Comment: before that loading bar comes im seeing white screen..how can I avoid that..plz help me